# Wait for library method to finish before continuing

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem. I have to wait for a method I call from a library to finish before I can continue with my code. How can I do that? My code:

```
Random random = new Random();
int node1 = random.nextInt(graph.getNumberOfVertices() + 1);
int node2 = random.nextInt(graph.getNumberOfVertices() + 1);

MatrixWrappedPath path = graph.getShortestPath(node1, node2);
        
int pathLength = 0;
if (path != null) {
    pathLength = path.getLength();
}
```

The exception I'm getting from the library (http://grph.inria.fr/javadoc/index.html) is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot compute a distance because the two vertices are not connected
>
> at grph.algo.distance.DistanceMatrix.getDistance(DistanceMatrix.java:56)
>
> at grph.MatrixWrappedPath.getLength(MatrixWrappedPath.java:47)

The DistanceMatrix class runs a BFS (org.dipergrafs.algo.bfs.BFSAlgorithm) which is Multithreaded (org.dipergrafs.algo.SingleSourceSearchAlgorithm, method "compute":

```
public R[] compute(final Grph g, IntSet sources)
{
final R[] r = createArray(sources.getGreatest() + 1);

new MultiThreadProcessing(g.getVertices(), Grph.getNumberOfThreadsToCreate()) {

    @Override
    protected void run(int threadID, int source)
    {
    r[source] = compute(g, source);
    }

};

return r;
}
```

) and fills the DistanceMatrix. So if DistanceMatrix is not finished yet, the getDistance(node1, node2) method cannot get the values from the DistanceMatrix.
I read about `CountDownLatch` and `wait()`, `notify()`, but I can't figure out how to do this. What would be a good way to solve this?

Comment: what do you mean by `path.getLength()` throws an exception? is it a NullPointerException or is it some Exception in the Library? What Library are you using?

Comment: I'd start by reading the doc that comes with the library (also add a pointer to the lib's webpage if such a page exists), because that kind of behaviour should really be explained in the documentation.

Comment: Eh?  I don't understand?  If the function/subsystem returns a path, it should be valid upon the return.  If the function/subsystem threads off the functionality and so needs to return a path later, it cannot return it directly. Usually, a callback is involved somewhere.

Comment: The library I'm using is: http://grph.inria.fr here the javadoc: http://grph.inria.fr/javadoc/index.html The exception comes from the framework:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot compute a distance because the two vertices are not connected
at grph.algo.distance.DistanceMatrix.getDistance(DistanceMatrix.java:56) at grph.MatrixWrappedPath.getLength(MatrixWrappedPath.java:47)
    
@MartinJames this is the case, the function threads off the functionality and returns the path later.

Comment: There is no indication in [the documentation](http://grph.inria.fr/javadoc/grph/Grph.html#getShortestPath(int,%20int)) that this function is asynchronous and, as @MartinJames says, it wouldn't really make sense for it to be either. So, you've made a mistake or a misassumption somewhere.

Comment: So I did some digging in the library and it turns out that the problem is an encapsulated bfs, which is computed by threads to build a DistanceMatrix and then the distance of the two nodes is returned as pathlength... So the problem is burried deep in the library, but my problem remains the same. How can I wait for it to finish?

Comment: Please see the original post, I edited some more details!

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong when assuming there is a multithreading issue there.

The error message is very clear :

```
(...)cannot compute a distance because the two vertices are not connected
```

You're taking 2 random nodes in a graph, but these nodes are not connected. that's why the library cannot compute its distance.

Are you sure you didn't forget to add the edges in your graph ? ;)

Comment: The path exists because otherwise it would be null and I would get a NullPointerException (from javadoc of getShortestPath()):
Returns: a shortest path from source to destination, or null if no path can be found.